# Solution to $ xy \ \frac {d^2y} {dx^2} + (x\ \frac {dy}{dx} - 2\ y) \frac {dy}{dx} = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How can I find the general solution to this:

$ xy \ \frac {d^2y} {dx^2} + (x\  \frac {dy}{dx} - 2\ y) \frac {dy}{dx} = 0$

I have learned various methods including: 
1. integrating factor method 
2. undetermined coefficient 
3. variations of parameters 
4. bernoulli equation 
5. cauchy euler 
6. second order ODE with constant coefficient 
7. reduction of order 
8. separation of variable

But none seems to be applicable to this one.
I have tried various ways arranging the equation to this:

$xy \ y'' = - (xy'-2y)y'$ 
 or 
$y'' + y^{-1} y'' - 2x^{-1} \ y' = 0$ 
But then I'm stuck. Any help would be apreciated! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write it this way:
$$x\Bigl(y\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+\Bigl(\frac{dy}{dx}\Bigr)^2\Bigr)=2y\frac{dy}{dx}\ .$$
You should recognise the first bracketed expression as
$$\frac{d}{dx}\Bigl(y\frac{dy}{dx}\Bigr)\ .$$
So substitute
$$u=y\frac{dy}{dx}\ ,$$
and I think you should be able to do the rest.

Comment: I find this solution really enlightening, thanks david!

Comment: Differential equations with lots of products like $yy'$ and $(y')^2$ are usually pretty hopeless unless the person who wrote the question has inserted some trick like this!

Answer (score 4):

Inspection prior any method learned is often useful to simplify.

In the present case, changing $y$ to $-y$ doesn't change the equation. This draw to the change of function 
$$y^2=u$$
which reduces the ODE to 
$$xu''-2u'=0$$
Separable, straightforward integrable.